# Вывод PHP кода в Twig

Tags: php, twig

Подскажите будьте добры как переделать код

```
<?php
             if ($prod_quant>0) echo "<button type='button' id='button-cart' data-loading-text='{{ text_loading }}' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'>{{ button_cart }}</button>";
             else echo "<button type='button' id='button-cart' data-loading-text='{{ text_loading }}' class='btn btn-inverse btn-lg btn-block' style='color:#ffffff' disabled>$stock</button>";
             ?>]]>
```

под twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {% if prod_quant > 0 %} 
     <button type='button' id='button-cart' data-loading-text='{{ text_loading }}' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'>{{ button_cart }}</button>
  {% else %} 
     <button type='button' id='button-cart' data-loading-text='{{ text_loading }}' class='btn btn-inverse btn-lg btn-block' style='color:#ffffff' disabled>{{ stock }}</button>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!